# Why does my knife leave grey streaks in the butter?

Tags: equipment, utensils

Sometimes my flatware leaves grey streaks in butter.  I've only seen this with knives in cold butter.  They claim to be stainless steel which I would think wouldn't do this. If I recall they were the very best flatware Target had to offer ;) Is something leaching into my food?

[image]

Comment: Clean your knife.

Comment: Might this be a knife shaped object made of aluminium, that has been bin the dishwasher?

Comment: It could be (black) rust. Which means you put it in the dishwasher *way* too dirty. Or it sat dirty in the sink for a month...

Answer (score 13):

The photo suggests you are using a knife that has serrations.  Dirt can get trapped between the serrations. This is not likely to be metal from the knife, but the dirt.

Comment: I'd wager its a bit of char from a piece of toast, jammed up in the serration.